# Sonata user bundle listing error

Tags: symfony

I am getting below error when i try  to access  user listing(user/list).

#### An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array") in "SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig".

I  had verified  mappings using app/console  doctrine:mapping:info and it is all fine

```
[OK]   Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseGallery
[OK]   Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseGalleryHasMedia
[OK]   Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseMedia
[OK]   Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
[OK]   Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
[OK]   Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
[OK]   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
[OK]   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
[OK]   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup
[OK]   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser
[OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Entity\Group
[OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Answer (score 0):

The  issue happened because of corrupted entry in `fos_user_user` table. This happened when i tried to create user using command `app/console fos:user:create --super-admin`  and  row created  have username, roles as empty which triggered  error.

I had removed the corrupted row and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Every User in Sonata Admin with roles=null, will generate this error, to solve this search the database table user for Rules with empty or Null then delete or Update these Users